# Improving Python code - row calculations based on certain columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am fairly new in the Python world, so my code is not yet that "pythonic".  I have a database of a few thousand rows in which each row represents a pub/cafe and, for each month of the year, I have a number from 0-1 (0-100%) that tells me how much, per average, that pub has been full. For example, the pub "Python Friends" has been full from January-October, but half full in the last 2 months of the year ([example photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1E20.png)).
The main goal of this task is to calculate the average coverage for each pub, so it's a row-by-row calculation, but the problems is that some pubs only started their business in a certain month, and so I need to take into consideration only those columns (for example if it started in June I only calculate the last 6 columns). Likewise, some closed in a certain month so I don't take into consideration that.
[here is an example of a few rows in which each combination is present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6Sel.png)

As per my instructions, I need to multiply each month's coverage by the number of days of that month, add all these months together and then divide by the number of total days. For example, if a pub has coverage only for the last 3 months of the year and the coverage is 100% each month, I will do the following calculation: (31 * 1 + 30 * 1 + 31 * 1)/92

I tried the following code but I am certain it can be improved upon, as I wait a really long time for it to compile even if I have a fairly decent laptop. Also, I need to improve upon this and make other calculations, for example get the quarterly data coverage, so my code is not that great at the moment. What can be improved?

```
#create dictionary to get months data
months = {'January' : 31,
          'February': 29,
          'March' : 31,
          'April': 30,
          'May' : 31,
          'June': 30,
          'July' : 31,
          'August': 31,
          'September' : 30,
          'October': 31,
          'November' : 30,
          'December': 31
        }

tobeappended = []
for i,j,m in zip(df['Start Month'],df['End Month'],df.index):
    if (i!='Not Available') & (j!='Not Available'): #data coverage for those rows in which both 'Active From' and 'Active To' exist
        middlemonths = 0
        totaldays = 0
        calc=0
        newdf= df.loc[m:m,i:j] # make a subset of the current dataframe view in the for loop, to be able to acces its columns
        for u in range(0,len(newdf.columns)): #get row calculation of days of coverage, then divide by total number of days
            middlemonths += newdf.iloc[:,u] * months[newdf.columns[u]]
        totaldays = np.array([months[x] for x in newdf.columns]).sum()
        calc = middlemonths / totaldays
        calc = calc.item()
        tobeappended.append(calc) #list of coverages for those rows in which active to/active from are available, from the same year as the data
    elif(i!='Not Available') & (j=='Not Available'):
        aftermonths = 0
        totaldays = 0
        calc = 0
        newdf = df.loc[m:m,i:'December']
        for u in range(0, len(newdf.columns)):
            aftermonths += newdf.iloc[:,u] * months[newdf.columns[u]]
        totaldays = np.array([months[x] for x in newdf.columns]).sum()
        calc = aftermonths / totaldays
        calc = calc.item()
        tobeappended.append(calc)
    elif(i=='Not Available') & (j!='Not Available'):
        beforemonths = 0
        totaldays = 0
        calc = 0
        newdf = df.loc[m:m,'January':j]
        for u in range(0, len(newdf.columns)):
            beforemonths += newdf.iloc[:,u] * months[newdf.columns[u]]
        totaldays = np.array([months[x] for x in newdf.columns]).sum()
        calc = beforemonths / totaldays
        calc = calc.item()
        tobeappended.append(calc)
    else:
        newdf = df.loc[m:m, 'January':'December']
        allmonths = 0
        for u in range(0, len(newdf.columns)):
            allmonths += newdf.iloc[:,u] * months[newdf.columns[u]]
        totaldays = np.array([months[x] for x in newdf.columns]).sum()
        calc = allmonths / totaldays
        calc = calc.item()
        tobeappended.append(calc)
    
tobeappended = np.array(tobeappended)
df['Data Coverage'] = tobeappended
```

P.S: this is not the whole code, I needed to do some cleaning before.
As I said, my main goal is to improve upon this code and make it faster, more pythonic, in order to add more parts to it easily. I know that this is a long post, and should there be any questions, please let me know and I will provide it. Thank you for your help and time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be different ways to do what you want. One option could be to have a [melted](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) DataFrame.

For example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Asset': ['Python Friends', 'Flying Dudes', 'Polterger', 'Beerzone'],
    'January': [1, 0, 1, 0],
    'February': [1, .5, 1, 0],
    'March': [np.nan, .5, 1, .5],
    'April': [1, .5, 1, 1],
    'May': [1, 1, 1, 1],
    'June': [1, 1, 1, 1],
    'July': [1, 1, 1, 1],
    'August': [1, 0, 1, 1],
    'September': [1, 0, 1, 0],
    'October': [1, 0, 1, 0],
    'November': [.5, 0, 1, 0],
    'December': [.5, 0, 1, 0],
    'Start Month': ['Not Available', 'Not Available', 'May', 'June'],
    'End Month': ['Not Available', 'April', 'Not Available', 'August'],
})
```

You can create a melted DataFrame such as

```
melt_df = df.melt(
    id_vars=['Asset', 'Start Month', 'End Month'], 
    var_name='Month', value_name='Coverage')
```

that will give

```
print(melt_df.head(5))

            Asset    Start Month      End Month     Month Coverage
0  Python Friends  Not Available  Not Available   January        1
1    Flying Dudes  Not Available          April   January        0
2       Polterger            May  Not Available   January        1
3        Beerzone           June         August   January        0
4  Python Friends  Not Available  Not Available  February      1.0
```

Now, a workaround could be to

- assign to each month name a number from `1` to `12`
- assign to `Not Available` in `Start Date` column a value of `0`
- assign to `Not Available` in `End Date` column a value of `13`

For example

```
month_map = {
    0: 0,
    'January': 1,
    'February': 2,
    'March': 3,
    'April': 4,
    'May': 5,
    'June': 6,
    'July': 7,
    'August': 8,
    'September': 9,
    'October': 10,
    'November': 11,
    'December': 12,
    13: 13,
}

melt_df['Month'] = melt_df.Month.map(month_map)

melt_df.loc[melt_df['Start Month']=='Not Available', 'Start Month'] = 0
melt_df.loc[melt_df['End Month']=='Not Available', 'End Month'] = 13

melt_df['Start Month'] = melt_df['Start Month'].map(month_map)
melt_df['End Month'] = melt_df['End Month'].map(month_map)
```

Now we can assign `NaN` to all coverages in months not included in `Start Month` to `End Month`

```
# we presume that End Month means
# that it stops at the end of the month
melt_df.loc[
    (melt_df.Month<melt_df['Start Month'])
    |
    (melt_df.Month>melt_df['End Month'] + 1),
    'Coverage'
] = np.nan
```

and drop all `NaN`s so we'll have only wanted values

```
melt_df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

To deal with months and calculate the average coverage, it's maybe better to do it with builtin [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html?highlight=to_datetime#pandas.to_datetime) (if you know the year)

```
melt_df['year_month'] = "2020-" + melt_df.Month.astype(str)
melt_df['year_month'] = pd.to_datetime(melt_df.year_month)
```

and then, for each `Asset`, [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html?highlight=resample#pandas.DataFrame.resample) to daily with [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html?highlight=fillna#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) method to fill `NaN`s and compute the mean (excluding the last day, that would be in the next month)

```
for asset in melt_df.Asset.unique():
    _df = melt_df[melt_df.Asset==asset].copy(deep=True)
    _df.set_index('year_month', inplace=True)
    _df = _df.resample('D', closed='left').mean()
    _df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
    print(asset, f"{_df.iloc[:-1].Coverage.mean():.1%}")
    # exclude last day  ^^^^^^^^^

Python Friends 95.5%
Flying Dudes 37.2%
Polterger 100.0%
Beerzone 100.0%
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! I learned a lot from it. I have a question: why does Flying Dudes have 49.5% coverage? It has 4 active months, so it should be (0+0.5+0.5+0.5)/4 = 37.5%, or around that. I can't figure out why its 49.5%, which would be only if it takes into consideration 3 months and leaves out the month with 0.

Comment: Hi. Sorry my fault, I'm gonna update the answer. Anyhow, it depends also on what you mean by `End Month`: it could mean that ended the 1st day of the month or the last day of the month. So, if you take into account the months only (not the days) it would be (0+0.5+0.5+0.5)/4 = 37.5% if you mean if ended at the end of April or (0+0.5+0.5)/3 = 33.3% if you mean it ended the 1st of April. If you want the days (so resample with `D`) you first need to define what `End Month` mean and it'd be a little bit more tricky.

Comment: No problem! By end month it means that it ends on the last day of the month, I do not take the days into consideration. So, in my original formula, the data coverage for each cell (0,0.5, etc) will be multiplied by the number of days in that month (30,31) and then the sum of that will be divided by the sum of number of days in those months (30+31+30+31 in this example). Basically a weighted average.

Comment: Ok now it's correct. It's not exactly 37.5% because months have different lenghts.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much! Where would I need to update the code so that it calculates coverage for each quarter? So Q1 will only take into consideration the first 3 months, etc.

Comment: You can simply create another column, for example `Period`, then assign a value based on periods you defined, for example `melt_df.loc[melt_df.Month.isin(np.arange(1, 4)), 'Period'] = 'First Quarter'` (this will take 1...3, remember that `np.arange` exclude the upper limit) and finally, after resampling if needed, you can `groupby` the period and compute the mean, for example `melt_df.groupby('Period').Coverage.mean()`